# FLATFILECONSUMER Cron task not picking up files. MAXIMO

Tags: ibm, websphere, tivoli

I have an instance of a the FLATFILECONSUMER cron task that is not picking up files. I can manually import the files but that's not fun.

```
Cron Task: FLATFILECONSUMER
Class: psdi.iface.load.LoadFlatFileCronTask
Access Level: FULL
Cron Task Instance Name: MyCoolTask
Schedule: 30s,,,,,,,,,*
Run as User: MAXADMIN
Active? X
Keep History? X
Max Number of History Records: 1,000
DELIMITER: ,
ISFILEEXTRACT: 1 (I have tried this set to 0, it doesn't seem to make a difference.)
SOURCEDIRECTORY: C:\work\COM\MAXIMOFILES\
TARGETENABLED: 1 (I have tried this set to 0, it doesn't seem to make a difference.)
TEXTQUALIFIER: "
```

This cron task shows up in the logs.

11/11/09 15:27:12:988 MST 00000047 SystemOut O 11 Nov 2009 15:27:12:988 INFO BMXAA6372I - Host name: 192.168.4.2. Server name: MXServer. Cron task name: FLATFILECONSUMER.MyCoolTask. Last run: 2009-11-11 14:52:03.0

11/11/09 15:27:13:003 MST 0000007d SystemOut O 11 Nov 2009 15:27:13:003 INFO Flat file polling task::FLATFILECONSUMER.MyCoolTask started for folder:C:\work\COM\MAXIMOFILES\

But that is. No error. No other info. And the records never show up in the table. I have changed the logger to DEBUG and still nothing useful in the log file.

Any ideas?

I would add a MAXIMO tag but I'm not that cool here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the files I wanted Maximo to import. Files for Maximo to import using a cron task MUST have an extension. I had files called data, data2, data3.

To make it work:

```
Make the changes Joe suggested.
Delete the files with out an extension.
Restart the application server (JVM).
Rename my files to:
   data.foo, data.bs, data.anythingYouCanThinkOf
Move the renamed files into the pick up directory.
```

Sit back and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Set TARGETENABLED to 0 and restart Maximo.

If you have DEBUG logging enabled on the `maximo.integration` logger, you should start seeing "FLAT file cron task::cronAction called" messages every 30 seconds.